# How to apply a MAX() function for a default value in a SQL table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a SQL table with some columns include one with primary key and auto_increment. And I want to add a column with a default value and I want this default value to be like : `COALESCE(MAX(priorite)+1, 1)` but of course it didn't work in my `Alter table`. How can I do ?

for the `CREATE TABLE` We could say that's it something like :

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    priorite INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I work on MariaDB. The auto_increment isn't sufficient because :

e.g : If I have 4 line id : (1,2,3,4) priorite : (1,2,3,4) here auto_increment equal priorite but if i remove a line (for example id = 2) pirorite will be reoganizez to become : id(1,3,4) priorite(1,2,3). Also if i add a new line, it has to be : id(1,3,4,5) priorite(1,2,3,4).

This table will be used by a php script. Indeed, I'm looking for a query to insert properly something like that : `INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn) VALUES (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(priorite)+1, 1) FROM myTable` but here I also have a SQL error.

I don't want (unless it's the only way) to run first a `SELECT MAX` and then an `Insert` with the result of the first query.

Thank you !

Comment: If you want `priorite` to be one larger than any priority in the table, then you probably need to use a trigger.  But why isn't the auto incremented id sufficient?

Comment: MAX() - or queries in general - can’t be used as a default value. The specific SQL engine/documentation should explain the requirements in greater detail.

Comment: please tag the question with a database you are using (mysql,sqlserver,or..) and provide table(s) structure as ```CREATE TABLE ...``` statement(s).

Comment: @GordonLinoff auto_increment is not sufficient because when a line is removed I will reorganize each line from 1 to my number of line (i hope you understand). 

e.g :  I have 4 line : with id : 1,2,3,4 and same for priority. But if i delete line with id=2 for example, i want that all the other line keep priority like 1,2,3 (and keep id like 1,3,4).

Comment: @user2864740 I know that's why I ask to find a solution

Comment: @ИгорьТыра I'm on mariadb (don't know the version sry) and for the CREATE TABLE We could say that's it something like : 

`CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   priorite INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB; `

Comment: @GordonLinoff Trigger won't work because it can't modify the table that the trigger is attached to.

Comment: what if the table is 1000000 records. and the record with id=1 is deleted.... all others must be recalculated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff and also but i think it's obvious, if I add a new line after, idc that the id become 5 but the priority must be 4.

Comment: @ИгорьТыра yes that how it will work (but the table will probably never have more than 20 rows)

Comment: If the data for an `INSERT` comes from a `SELECT` query, you don't put `VALUES` before it. Just `INSERT INTO tablename (columnnames...) SELECT ...`

Comment: I don't think there's any way to make it automatically renumber the column every time a row is added or deleted.

Comment: no chance of default recalculation. if a table is not going to be huge, better to calculate such a value on the fly or in the ```VIEW``` (with some sort of ```ROW_NUMBER()over(ORDER by id)``` or whatever ranking/numbering functions are there in mariadb)

Comment: @Barmar Thank you ! Now I can insert easily !!! 

For the removing i think i will do it with PHP

Comment: How about `SET @max = (SELECT MAX(priorite) FROM myTable); INSERT INTO myTable (priorite) VALUES (@max);` - Or as subselect - or do you want to update all entries and count up `priorite`?

Comment: @Pilan about the insertion, I tryed with the Barmar's answer and it works successfully, for the update, theoretically, all lines with a priority higher than the one wich is deleted will decrease by one.